# black box surrounding the browser address bar after installing google analytics

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

I have recently added google analytics to my website, and since then I'm getting some strange behavior from time to time.

Namely, when the page is being idle for a while in a minimized window state, 
I sometimes get a **black strip** (see the image) surrounding the address bar of Google Chrome browser when I open the webpage (just maximizing it from Windows toolbar) .

[image: black_strip]

I'm certain this is due to Google Analytics, as before adding that nothing like this has ever happened.

Here is the code I use following the instructions provided at official google analytics page

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XX-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());

   gtag('config', 'XX-XXXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

This code is inserted as the first item after the  tag (on all pages I track).

Any ideas what the **black strip** means and what might be causing it?

I did not observe similar behavior in other browsers (firefox or edge), this seems to be happening in google chrome only.

Also, when I hover the mouse over the black region it disappears and things get back to normal.